# Past events in reporting speech

Tags: past-perfect, reported-speech

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/gurgaon/stripped-beaten-with-shoes-and-sticks-by-bosses-says-manipur-man/articleshow/56633937.cms

This is with reference to the sentence in above news Link.

> "Where the employers tried to convince him not to reveal he was thrashed."

If I used past perfect in above sentence I.e.

> "Where the employers tried to convince him not to reveal that he had been thrashed."

This is because I want to refer to the event of thrashing that was started and finished in the past. It will also give idea of completed event at the time of convincing by employer. This is require to give emphasis on thrashing event which is happened before hospitalization and before employers convincing to him.  Using simple past is only giving idea of past event of trashing.

Please help me to understand if my version is correct?

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with your version.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct as written.  I imagine the reason the newspaper writer chose not to use the past perfect is that the past tense is sufficient to convey the necessary information.  In many cases, the perfect tense isn't *necessary* to convey the order of events, but it can help and it sounds good when properly used.